# Getting wrong data using Apollo

Tags: angular, apollo

I'm trying to get some data using Apollo. Here's the simple query:

```
export const CurrentUserForProfile = gql`

    query getGroupDetails($groupId: Long, $groupType: String, $tags: [Tag]) {
        nodes: NodesRelay (
          first: 50
          where: {
            tags: { CONTAINS: $tags },
            OR: {
              AND: {
                nsParentId: { EQ: $groupId }
                nsParentType: { EQ: $groupType }
              }
              superGroupNodeLinks: {
                groupId: { EQ: $groupId }
                groupType: { EQ: $groupType }
              }
            }
          }
        ) {
          elements {
            data {
              ...nodeFields
              ext {
                ...nodeExtFields
              }
            }
          }
          pageInfo {
            ...pageInfoFields
          }
        }
      }

      fragment nodeFields on Node {
        id {
          id
          type
        }
        subtype
        internalId
        businessId
        scadaId
        isGroup
        isTemporary
        nsParentId
        nsParentType
        ouId
        description
        shortDescription
        status
        isNsPowered
        tags
        owners
        notes
        version
      }

      fragment nodeExtFields on NodeExt {
        id {
          id
          type
        }
        asParentId
        asParentType
        isAsPowered
        isAsInconsistent
        isAsPoweredInParallel
        isAsPoweredByExtSource
        isAsPoweredByDiffSource
        maneuverId
        entityStatusMap
        createdAt
        createdBy
        updatedAt
        updatedBy
        version
      }

      fragment pageInfoFields on PageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        hasPreviousPage
        startCursor
        endCursor
      }
    `;
```

and the way i'm using it is as the tutorial say:

```
this.data = this.apollo
            .watchQuery({
                query: CurrentUserForProfile,
                variables: {
                    "groupId": 15,
                    "groupType": "sec_subst",
                    "tags": ["GIS"]
                },
                fetchResults: true,
                returnPartialData: false,
            }).valueChanges
            .pipe(
                map((res: any) => res.data.nodes.elements)
            )
```

the HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let a of data | async">
    {{a.data.id.type}} <br>
  </ng-container>
```

What I'm getting is just 10 lines of `"lv_line"`.
If I change the logic, subscribing in the component and doing a `console.log(data)` I see the same things. This could be correct, but is not. The data I'm getting is totally wrong, and If I check in the network tab, no matter what the logic in my application is, the data is correct and is not just an array of 10 elements with a property `type` always being "lv_line".

Here's the network result:

[image]

while the HTML result looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I've tried everything I could possibly think of without any success, getting the same wrong result try after try.

Answer (score 0):

After hours and hours I've managed to solve the issue. By simply using a `no-cache` fetchPolicy all the problems are gone.

```
this.data = this.apollo
            .watchQuery({
                query: CurrentUserForProfile,
                variables: {
                    "groupId": 15,
                    "groupType": "sec_subst",
                    "tags": ["GIS"]
                },
                fetchResults: true,
                returnPartialData: false,
                fetchPolicy: "no-cache" // <-------
            }).valueChanges
            .pipe(
                map((res: any) => res.data.nodes.elements)
            )
```